# Android - Convert Button to TextView at runtime

Tags: android, button, runtime, textview

Is it possible to convert a Button into a TextView onclick during runtime?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a Layout that hold both TextView and Button.
At runtime just set ones `setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)` and the other `setVisibility(Visibility.INVISIBLE)`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a bad design.

Hide the button and show instead a TextView.

Comment: Yes, that is what I intend to do. What I want to know is how can I declare both a TextView and a Button in the same position in the XML?

Comment: Keep both the views in FrameLayout and based on your needs make the particular view invisible/gone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ViewSwitcher that is very best technique
Here just change edittext with button Simple :)

e.g

> XML

```
<ViewSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/my_switcher"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/clickable_text_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="TextViewClicked"
                android:text="abc"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/hidden_edit_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="12"
                android:text="12"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </EditText>
        </ViewSwitcher>
```

> JAVA

```
    ViewSwitcher my_switcher;
my_switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.my_switcher);
TextView profile_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickable_text_view);

profile_name.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
TextViewClicked();
}
        });
```

> TextViewClicked()

```
public void TextViewClicked() {
        my_switcher.showNext(); //or switcher.showPrevious();
        TextView myTV = (TextView) my_switcher.findViewById(R.id.clickable_text_view);
        myTV.setText("value");
    }
```

Hope it help